# How to count two columns created in a Select statement and group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm not sure if my question makes sense yet, but looking at my code I guess it should. I'm having trouble coming up with NumberOfPurchases based on columuns created in the Select statement. So in the select statement there are two columns based on a case statement, they are OrderNumber and Price category. Now I need to count all the orders, for example all the rows named PurchaseOrder that are also 1.Low Price and all the rows named PurchaseOrder and 2.AveragePRice and so on. That's why it needs to be grouped by, the OrderNumber and PriceCategory are elements that do not participate in the GroupBy clause but are inputs to the aggregate function that should be in the NumberOfPurchases column. So it's legal to have them in the select statement when grouping. I have provided the code below, the rest of the code has been commented out since I haven't gottent to it.

```
select OrderNumber = CASE 
                      WHEN (orderid % 10) > 7 THEN 'Purchase Order'
                      WHEN (orderid % 10) < 2 THEN 'Discounted Order'
                      WHEN (orderid % 2)  = 1 THEN 'Special Order'
                      WHEN (orderid % 2)  = 0 THEN 'Open Markent Purchase Agreement'
                      ELSE 'Missing Value' END
, PriceCategory = CASE 
                WHEN val < 1000 THEN '1. Low Price'
                WHEN val >= 1000 AND val <= 3000 THEN '2. Average Price'
                WHEN val > 3000 THEN '3.High End Price'
                ELSE 'Missing Value' END
, NumberOfPurchases = --Not sure what to write here
--, TotalCost =
--, AverageTotalCost=
from Sales.OrderValues
group by OrderNumber, PriceCategory
order by PriceCategory,OrderNumber
```

I have tried different ways of counting but one of my issues is when I write something like, CASE WHEN OrderNumber = 'something' the column is not recognized. Not surprised that happened. Here is the expected output.[image]

The following code should help visualising what is going on.

```
select OrderNumber = CASE 
                      WHEN (orderid % 10) > 7 THEN 'Purchase Order'
                      WHEN (orderid % 10) < 2 THEN 'Discounted Order'
                      WHEN (orderid % 2)  = 1 THEN 'Special Order'
                      WHEN (orderid % 2)  = 0 THEN 'Open Markent Purchase Agreement'
                      ELSE 'Missing Value' END
, PriceCategory = CASE 
                WHEN val < 1000 THEN '1. Low Price'
                WHEN val >= 1000 AND val <= 3000 THEN '2. Average Price'
                WHEN val > 3000 THEN '3.High End Price'
                ELSE 'Missing Value' END
--, NumberOfPurchases =
--, TotalCost =
--, AverageTotalCost=
from Sales.OrderValues
--group by OrderNumber, PriceCategory
order by PriceCategory,OrderNumber
```

I get this output

```
Discounted Order    1. Low Price
Discounted Order    1. Low Price
Discounted Order    1. Low Price
Discounted Order    1. Low Price
.
.
.
88 rows as the previous statement


Open Markent Purchase Agreement 1. Low Price
Open Markent Purchase Agreement 1. Low Price
Open Markent Purchase Agreement 1. Low Price
Open Markent Purchase Agreement 1. Low Price
Open Markent Purchase Agreement 1. Low Price
Open Markent Purchase Agreement 1. Low Price
.
.
130 rows of the previous statement

Purchase Order  1. Low Price
Purchase Order  1. Low Price 
Purchase Order  1. Low Price
.
.
82 rows of the previous statement
Special Order   1. Low Price
Special Order   1. Low Price
Special Order   1. Low Price
Special Order   1. Low Price
Special Order   1. Low Price
.
.
127 rows of the  previous statement

Discounted Order    2. Average Price
Discounted Order    2. Average Price
Discounted Order    2. Average Price
Discounted Order    2. Average Price
Discounted Order    2. Average Price
.
.
57 rows of the previous statement

Open Markent Purchase Agreement 2. Average Price
Open Markent Purchase Agreement 2. Average Price
Open Markent Purchase Agreement 2. Average Price
.
.
97 rows of the previous statement
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data ?

Comment: I'm using the database TSQLV4 it can be downloaded from, http://tsql.solidq.com/resources/ Sales.OrderValues is the table being manipulated. lf you wihs you can run the Sales.OrderValues to see all the columns. Also if the code is run commenting out the Group By, gives a good view of what i'm tryin to do . I will post it tho.

Comment: Ok i will download it and edit my answer.

Comment: How do you expect data `NumberOfPurchases` to be generated

Comment: check my question i just edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlserver does not support `group by` with Alias

You could make a subquery  get the `OrderNumber`,`PriceCategory` data,then you can group by on`OrderNumber`,`PriceCategory`.

Simple way you can do like this.

```
SELECT 
    OrderNumber,
    PriceCategory,
    COUNT(1) AS 'NumberOfPurchases',
    AVG(val) as 'AverageTotalCost',
    SUM(val) as 'TotalCost'
FROM
(
SELECT 
  OrderNumber = CASE 
                      WHEN (orderid % 10) > 7 THEN 'Purchase Order'
                      WHEN (orderid % 10) < 2 THEN 'Discounted Order'
                      WHEN (orderid % 2)  = 1 THEN 'Special Order'
                      WHEN (orderid % 2)  = 0 THEN 'Open Markent Purchase Agreement'
                      ELSE 'Missing Value' END
, PriceCategory = CASE 
                WHEN val < 1000 THEN '1. Low Price'
                WHEN val >= 1000 AND val <= 3000 THEN '2. Average Price'
                WHEN val > 3000 THEN '3.High End Price'
                ELSE 'Missing Value' END
,val
from Sales.OrderValues
) AS T
GROUP BY OrderNumber,PriceCategory
order by PriceCategory,OrderNumber
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: @XavierMaldonado I edit my answer :), add `NumberOfPurchases` field

Comment: That was fast, you are pretty good. It's still missing that column NumberOfPurchases. I'm not sure why but it was asked to be done as,  'group by  OrderNumber, PriceCategory' I believe that those elements should be there since we are suppoose to sum them in the NumberOfPurchases. I got this statement from my book TSQL Fundamentals " Elements that do not participate in the GROUP BY clause are allowed only as inputs to an aggregate
function such as COUNT, SUM, AVG, MIN, or MAX". Pretty much that is my challenge on how to get it to work.

Comment: This query is legal                                                                    SELECT
empid,
YEAR(orderdate) AS orderyear,
COUNT(DISTINCT custid) AS numcusts
FROM Sales.Orders
GROUP BY empid, YEAR(orderdate);

Comment: When you use aggregate function,you need to group by on no aggregate field.The function `YEAR()` isn't a aggregate function so you need to `group by` it.

Comment: SQLServer didn't  support alias grouping

Comment: Not to familiar with subquery's. Count(1), the 1 refers to the sub query. I'm pretty sure the val in sthe sub query is returned gropued by that's how we are able to use it as an argument. Finally why do we write AS T for the sub query. Thank for your help.

Comment: `COUNT(1)` just means  count only you can also write `COUNT(VAL)` or `COUNT(5)`results are the same,
Since `OrderNumber `,`PriceCategory` fields are generated using `case when`, I use a subquery to generate a new result set  easier for me to use an aggregate function